# State/storage does not get mutated

Tags: substrate-node-template, rust, storage

I have the following case:

```rs
let contract = Invoice {
  origin: from.clone(),
  to: to.clone(),
  amount,
  status: false,
  id: 17,
  msg: msg.clone(),
};

let mut invoice_vec: Vec<Invoice<T::AccountId, T::AccountId, BalanceOf<T>>> = Vec::new();
invoice_vec.push(contract);


// Save in storage the sender and the invoices
<InvoiceSender<T>>::insert(from.clone(), &invoice_vec);

InvoiceSender::<T>::mutate(&from, |invoice| {
  invoice_vec.iter_mut().filter(|i| i.id == 17).for_each(|i| {
    i.status = true;
  })
});
```

As you can see, I have created an Invoice object, I have put it inside an array and then I have stored it.

The issue happens when I try to mutate one of the contracts.

During debugging I can see that the following line `i.status = true;` is being executed, but the status is remains false, so the state was not mutated.

Comment: You are mutating it to false and the contract.status is set to false, so yes the status is still false

Comment: It was a lapsus. I changed it to true.

Answer (score 0):

There a couple of things I don't understand. If you have a `StorageMap<AccountId, Vec<Invoice>>`, when calling mutate, you need to use the `|invoice|` from the closure. You are modifying the outer vector `invoice_vec`, which is not persisted, it's just a temporary variable.

Does this solve it?

```rs
InvoiceSender::<T>::mutate(&from, |invoice| {
    invoice.iter_mut().filter(|i| i.id == 17).for_each(|i| { // <-- This line changed
        i.status = true;
    })
});
```

I'm not sure if you are trying to modify all the possible invoices of the user or just that one, but if you want to modify all the invoices that have `id==17`:

UPDATE: I've tested it locally using its repository, it just changes the status of the invoice, nothing else

```rs
if let Some(mut invoices_recevier) = Self::invoice_receiver(&to) {
    for invoice in &mut invoices_recevier {
        if invoice.id == id {
            invoice.status = true;
        }
    }
    InvoiceReceiver::<T>::insert(to.clone(), invoices_recevier);

    //...

    return Ok(());
}
```

Comment: I would like to edit only one with id 17 and if status is false

Comment: Still does not work :/

Comment: Where did you find the invoice for this method?

 
InvoiceSender::<T>::mutate(&from, |invoice| {
    invoice.iter_mut().filter(|i| i.id == 17).for_each(|i| { // <-- This line changed
        i.status = true;
    })
});

Comment: Line 209 is the method which needs to be fixed: https://github.com/herou/EscrowPallet/blob/invoice_system/pallets/invoice/src/lib.rs